# Android write ID to an empty NFC tag

Tags: android, tags, nfc

I made an app that reads NFC tags, but I face the issue that not all bands have an ID.

**Is it possible to assign a new ID to an empty tag?**

```
private String tagInfoId = "";
private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_player);
    if (!userPrefs.isLoggedIn().get()) finish();
    trackerService = ServiceGateway.createAuthorizedService(TrackerService.class);

    nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (nfcAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "NFC NOT supported on this devices!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else if (!nfcAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "NFC NOT Enabled!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        if (tag == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "tag == null");

            //here is possible to write a new tag code ???

        } else {
            byte[] tagId = tag.getId();
            for (int i = 0; i < tagId.length; i++) {
                tagInfoId += Integer.toHexString(tagId[i] & 0xFF);
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called with: " + "tagID:" + tagInfoId);

        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
   <activity
            android:name=".activities.NfcActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Also, if I assign an ID to a new tag, will it read it in the same way or do I have to change the above code?

Answer (score 0):

For an NFC intent, the intent extra TAG should never be empty (or `null`). Consequently, you should always get a `Tag` object from `intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)` and you should never branch into `if (tag == null) {`.

If you still reach the `tag == null` branch then this has nothing to do with the tag not having an identifier. It rather means that something went badly wrong in the NFC stack of your device. This might be, for instance, that tag reading was interrupted at a very early stage or that the tag does not properly speak the protocol that the reader expects. Since you did not receive a `Tag` object, there is also no way to communicate with the tag.

Consequently, there is not much you could do about this. You could only try to re-read the tag (by retapping it with your phone).